# JQ - pick up another higher level key value after array print

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have this JSON data:

price_history.json

```
{
  "candles": [
    {
      "open": 26,
      "high": 26.25,
      "low": 25.75,
      "close": 26.0625,
      "volume": 1038600,
      "datetime": 957762000000
    },
    {
      "open": 25.8125,
      "high": 26.25,
      "low": 25.75,
      "close": 26,
      "volume": 765900,
      "datetime": 957848400000
    }
  ],
  "symbol": "ABC",
  "empty": false
}
```

I need to get this to a CSV. I can get almost everything I need with the following filter, but I want to add the symbol that is outside the array:

```
cat price_history.json | jq '.candles[] | (.open|tostring) + "," + (.high|tostring)  + "," + (.low|tostring)  + "," + (.close|tostring)  + "," + (.volume|tostring)  + "," + (.datetime|tostring)'
```

response:

```
"26,26.25,25.75,26.0625,1038600,957762000000"
"25.8125,26.25,25.75,26,765900,957848400000"
```

desired response:

```
"26,26.25,25.75,26.0625,1038600,957762000000,ABC"
"25.8125,26.25,25.75,26,765900,957848400000,ABC"
```

I have tried many combinations trying to get back to the top level to pick up the symbol, including trying to pick it up first. I don't care where it sits in the line

This is the closest I got, it has everything but prints the keys and everything I don't need:

```
cat /home/utility/scripts/marketScan/app/modules/api-comm/tdam/port/input/price_history-2.txt | jq '(.candles[]|tostring) + "," + (.symbol|tostring)'
```

response

```
"{\"open\":26,\"high\":26.25,\"low\":25.75,\"close\":26.0625,\"volume\":1038600,\"datetime\":957762000000},ABC"
""{\"open\":25.8125,\"high\":26.25,\"low\":25.75,\"close\":26,\"volume\":765900,\"datetime\":957848400000},ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want valid CSV, it's usually best to use `@csv` in conjunction with the -r command-line option.
In your case, you could go with:

```
.symbol as $symbol
| .candles[]
| [.open, .high, .low, .close, .volume, .datetime, $symbol]
| @csv
```

or equivalently but without the $-variable:

```
(.candles[] | [.open, .high, .low, .close, .volume, .datetime]) + [.symbol]
| @csv
```

If you're willing to take the risk, you could also consider:

```
.symbol as $symbol
| .candles[]
| [.[], $symbol]
| @csv
```